# find не выводит файл с временем модификации меньше суток

Tags: linux, bash

Пытаюсь узнать, был ли модифицирован файл /mnt/cfgorthanc/ulist.json в течении последних 24 часов.

Для этого использую команду со следующими параметрами:

```
find /mnt/cfgorthanc/ulist.json -mtime -1
```

Дата модификации файла - Feb 4 2021 12:00:00

Проблема в том, что с параметром -1 файл выводится. Как и с параметром -2,-3, -500.
Если убрать минус - файл не выводится.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: `$ find /mnt/cfgorthanc -name ulist.json -mtime -1`

Answer (score 0):

Понял, в чем проблема. Время модификации, которое задается ключем -mtime в случае с минусом (-1, -2, -3.. etc) включает в себя 24-часовой период